# Filemaker xslt Import

Tags: xml, xslt, import, filemaker

There was another question very to this one but stopped short of my issue.  BTW, I am less than a newbie.

Here is the xml he used except I have modified it a bit.  I need a xslt doc that will do this import into FMP

```
<orders>
 <order>
  <order-no>1001</order-no>
   <line-items>
    <line-item>
     <product-id>knife</product-id>
     <product-id>Fork</product-id>
     <product-id>Spoon</product-id>
     <something>bbb</something>
     <something>ccc</something>
     <something>ddd</something>
   </line-item>
   <line-item>
     <product-id>plunger</product-id>
     <product-id>Brush</product-id>
     <product-id>Stool</product-id>
     <something>hhh</something>
     <something>jjj</something>
    <something>lll</something>
   </line-item>
  </line-items>
</orders>
```

What I need is an xslt that will show up in Filemaker import dialog screen something like this.

product-id > ProdID field in FMP
something > something field in FMP, but something need to be taken from the first line in something 
"Knife" > ProdID in FMP
"bbb" > something field
then the next record imported into FMP would be 2nd line and take the 2nd line from something
"Fork" > ProdID in FMP
"ccc" >something field
then the next record imported into FMP would be 3rd line and take the 3rd line from something
"Spoon" > ProdID in FMP
"ddd" > something field.

Than go to the next "line-item" element and do it all over again.

I hope this sense.  I have an xslt doc but I cant get it to select the 2nd,3rd... line of something when its on the 2nd,3rd line of ProdID.

I have been working on this for 2 days and am no closer to a solution. My xml is totally different than this, but if I know how to do it in this simplified xml, I can modify my xslt to suit.

Thanks for any help!

Scott

Comment: Your input is missing a closing </order> tag!

Comment: You are right, Im not concerned with that, just forgot to it when I copied.  Thx!

Comment: "*Im not concerned with that*" You should be: we copy your code and use it for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very difficult to understand your description. I *think* you want to use something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
        <METADATA>
            <FIELD NAME="ProductID" TYPE="TEXT"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Something" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        </METADATA>
        <RESULTSET>
            <xsl:for-each select="orders/order/line-items/line-item">
                <ROW>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="product-id[1]"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="something[1]"/></DATA></COL>
                </ROW>
                <ROW>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="product-id[2]"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="something[2]"/></DATA></COL>
                </ROW>
                <ROW>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="product-id[3]"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="something[3]"/></DATA></COL>
                </ROW>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RESULTSET>
    </FMPXMLRESULT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will create 3 records (with 2 fields each) for each line-item in your source XML.

**Note**: you must use FMP version 11 or higher in order for this to work.

---

### Edit:

> Lets say there are 21 productID as well as something on each
>   line-item?

If you have that many products in each line-item, use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
        <METADATA>
            <FIELD NAME="ProductID" TYPE="TEXT"/>
            <FIELD NAME="Something" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        </METADATA>
        <RESULTSET>
            <xsl:for-each select="orders/order/line-items/line-item">
                <xsl:for-each select="product-id">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
                    <ROW>
                        <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="."/></DATA></COL>
                        <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="../something[$i]"/></DATA></COL>
                    </ROW>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RESULTSET>
    </FMPXMLRESULT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Lets say there are 21 productID as well as something on each line-item?  I would like to be able to insert a # in the brackets '[$Loop]' based on the record# it is currently on.  Like a loop in FMP, if the loop is 1 then 1 gets inserted in between the brackets and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for the coding!  It seems to work just as you said!  Very short and sweet.  Thanks again!

Comment: Would do that if I could find an accept button.  Please instruct me how to accept it.